# Discarding variable when using ValueChanged and EventCallback<T>

Tags: c#, callback, blazor

I've tried searching for an answer without avail. If I have the following code:

`<MyObject Value="@SomeVariable" ValueChanged="@((decimal? value) => MyFunction())"`

Where `@SomeVariable` is, in this example, of type `decimal?`, `MyObject` is a generic typed object (IE `MyObject<T>`)

If `MyObject` were a normal class, I could write the code as follows:

`<MyObject Value="@SomeVariable" ValueChanged="@(_ => MyFunction())"`

However, if it's a generic typed object, I get the following exception:

`Error  CS1503  Argument 4: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback<decimal?>`

Any suggestions on how to address this? I mean of course, I can just leave the discarded variable in, but it seems like messy code to do that.

*** Edit to answer a question ***

The basic class / property signature would look like:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class MyObject<T> : ComponentBase
    {
        [Parameter] public T Value { get; set; }
        [Parameter] public EventCallback<T> ValueChanged { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post you `MyObject` code ?

Comment: MyObject is not yet cooked

Comment: @agua from mars - Updated my question with a sample MyObject class